# When to use existing branch and when to create a new one

Tags: git, github

Still learning a little more about how Git works. I'm currently working on a group project on Github. Someone's already created a branch and made commits on it. Should I make my own branch to add changes to the project or is it fine to use that other person's branch? I'm kind of confused on what the difference would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different workflows for Git; you should discuss with your team how you want to structure your branches so everyone adheres to the same guidelines.

Typically, you should make changes on your **own** branch first. You should create your branch at the same revision as your teammate's branch, so you have all of their work. After you're finished making your own contributions, you push the branch to GitHub so everyone has access to it.

Here's an example of the actual git commands:

```
git checkout teammate_branch  # Checkout your teammate's branch
git checkout -b my_branch     # Create your own branch
git commit -m "Changes"       # Make changes
git push origin my_branch     # Push your branch to GitHub
```

From there you can create a Pull Request for your teammates to review. Eventually, you'll probably want to merge that branch into your teammate's branch or the master branch, depending on what your team decides.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to make a new branch whenever you start working on a new feature or bugfix. That way other contributor's changes won't mess with your head while you're working.

Once your code is looking good, then it's time to merge that branch into the master. Just make sure you communicate with everyone that you're about to merge it.